# Time series: What's the most efficient way to write code for subsets?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two dataframes

df1

```
time x   y   state
...  ... ... CA
...  ... ... MA
...  ... ... TX
...  ... ... MA
...  ... ... CA
...  ... ... IL
```

df2

```
time x   y   state
...  ... ... MA
...  ... ... NY
...  ... ... MA
...  ... ... TX
...  ... ... CA
...  ... ... CA
```

I then have some code where I aggregate the monthly values, rename columns, match data with another list and subsequently merge df1 and df2 into one in about 50 lines of code. Here, I do not consider `state` so far.

However, I need to create subsets of the merged dataframe for several U.S. states. Is there a more elegant way other than just copy/pasting the code used for df1 and df2 and replacing df1 and df2 with df1_CA, df2_MA etc.

Loop? Panel data?

Comment: Have a `look at `split` and then `lapply` function (or loop). `split(df1,df1$state)`

Comment: Using `group_by` in `dplyr` might be suitable here

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a small reproducible example. I'm sorry I can't provide my original code.

Comment: @Fanny,  actually, it is _your_ job to provide a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use the data.table package for the grouped analyses.

```
# transform your data.frame to data.table
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# e.g. grouping values on state level
dt1[, sum(y), by=state]
# this will accumulate all y values by state
```

If you don't want to replace the df name in your code, you could define a function:

```
# define the function
accumulate <- function(df){
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  return(dt[, sum(y), by=state])
}

# and call it 
accumulate(df1)
accumulate(df2)
```

instead of a for loop or similar on all your data.frames, one could use one of the apply functions that iterate effectively through data structures, e.g. lists

```
# alternatively define a list of data.frames and then iterate over the list
my.dfs <- list(df1,df2)
lapply(my.dfs, accumulate(df))
```